# Python3 How to set up DataFrame from while loops

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, while-loop

I want to create a DataFrame that appends A_weights and B_weights as the columns; like this:

```
        A_weights     B_weights
weights    0              1
weights   0.01           0.99
weights   0.02           0.98
weights   0.03           0.97
weights   ...            ...
weights    1              0
```

So far, I've done this:

```
A_weights = -0.01
A_n = 1

B_weights = 1.01
B_n = 0

counter = 0.01

while A_weights < A_n:
    A_weights += counter
    print(round(A_weights,2))
print('\n')

while B_weights > B_n:
    B_weights -= counter
    print(round(B_weights,2))
    
weights_df = {'Weights_A': ['A_weights'],
        'Weights_B': ['B_weights']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(weights_df, columns = ['A_weights', 'B_weights'])

print (df)
```

Output

```
0.0
0.01
0.02
0.03
0.04
0.05
0.06
0.07
0.08
0.09
0.1
0.11
0.12
0.13
0.14
0.15
0.16
0.17
0.18
0.19
0.2
0.21
0.22
0.23
0.24
0.25
0.26
0.27
0.28
0.29
0.3
0.31
0.32
0.33
0.34
0.35
0.36
0.37
0.38
0.39
0.4
0.41
0.42
0.43
0.44
0.45
0.46
0.47
0.48
0.49
0.5
0.51
0.52
0.53
0.54
0.55
0.56
0.57
0.58
0.59
0.6
0.61
0.62
0.63
0.64
0.65
0.66
0.67
0.68
0.69
0.7
0.71
0.72
0.73
0.74
0.75
0.76
0.77
0.78
0.79
0.8
0.81
0.82
0.83
0.84
0.85
0.86
0.87
0.88
0.89
0.9
0.91
0.92
0.93
0.94
0.95
0.96
0.97
0.98
0.99
1.0


1.0
0.99
0.98
0.97
0.96
0.95
0.94
0.93
0.92
0.91
0.9
0.89
0.88
0.87
0.86
0.85
0.84
0.83
0.82
0.81
0.8
0.79
0.78
0.77
0.76
0.75
0.74
0.73
0.72
0.71
0.7
0.69
0.68
0.67
0.66
0.65
0.64
0.63
0.62
0.61
0.6
0.59
0.58
0.57
0.56
0.55
0.54
0.53
0.52
0.51
0.5
0.49
0.48
0.47
0.46
0.45
0.44
0.43
0.42
0.41
0.4
0.39
0.38
0.37
0.36
0.35
0.34
0.33
0.32
0.31
0.3
0.29
0.28
0.27
0.26
0.25
0.24
0.23
0.22
0.21
0.2
0.19
0.18
0.17
0.16
0.15
0.14
0.13
0.12
0.11
0.1
0.09
0.08
0.07
0.06
0.05
0.04
0.03
0.02
0.01
-0.0
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [GS_weights, FB_weights]
Index: []
```

I have managed to create a while Loop for both A_weights and B_weights. Please help me in tweaking the dataframe to set A_weights and B_weights as columns and displays the weights accordingly from the while loop.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: @Ruther Righart Hi, your answer was very helpful! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the values need to written to a list, which I call here nA_weights and nB_weights:

```
counter = 0.01
A_weights = -0.01
A_n = 1
B_weights = 1.01
B_n = 0
nA_weights = []
nB_weights = []

while A_weights < A_n:
    A_weights += counter
    nA_weights.append(A_weights)

while B_weights > B_n:
    B_weights -= counter
    nB_weights.append(B_weights)
```

The next step puts the lists in a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Weights_A':nA_weights, 'Weights_B':nB_weights})
```